# Use Linux to read contents of Windows encrypted folder

Tags: windows, encryption, ntfs

Windows allows the [selective encrypting](http://www.ehow.com/how_7211463_encrypt-contents-secure-data.html) of certain files or folders. I currently have a Windows folder that is set to "encrypt contents to secure data". (The Windows partition is NTFS.)

If I mount this drive under Linux, is there anyway to decrypt the contents of the directory so that I can read the files without having to reboot into Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [NTFS-3G FAQ](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#compressed), you can't read or write encrypted files:

> [...] Reading and writing transparently compressed files are fully supported, *but reading or writing encrypted files are not supported at the moment*. [...]

So you'll need to do that from Windows at this point.