# How can I tell If a file is NTFS encrypted?

Tags: encryption, ntfs

When I copied some files from work onto my external hard drive it copied them as encrypted files.

**NOTE:** The drive is not encrypted - just individual files.

Now when I try to copy files from the external drive to my PC, Nautilus crashes. In fact Nautilus crashes even when I browse a directory that contains an encrypted file.

I can browse the file system using the terminal, although I get "Permission Denied" errors if I try to copy the encrypted files. On Windows the encrypted files are listed in green in Windows explorer.

Is there anyway that I can list which files on the external drive are encrypted?

#### UPDATE #1

I understand that you cannot decrypt these encrypted files under Linux per this Q&AL [Use Linux to read contents of Windows encrypted folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60515/use-linux-to-read-contents-of-windows-encrypted-folder). However, I can list them in the terminal so I'm looking for a way to list which ones are encrypted and which ones are not.

Comment: With what were these files encrypted?

Comment: It was in a corporate environment where I no longer work. All the files on the work PC appeared to be encrypted. I assumed it was Windows built in but I don't know for sure.

Comment: File bug report on nautilus.